# I am computing a percentage in postgresql and I get the following unexpected behavior when dividing a number by the same number

Tags: postgresql, division

I am new at postgresql and am having trouble wrapping my mind around why I am getting the results that I see.

I perform the following query

```
SELECT
name AS region_name,
COUNT(tripsq1.id) AS trips,
COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS unique_users,
COUNT(case when consumed_at = start_at  then tripsq1.id end) AS first_day,
(SUM(case when consumed_at = start_at  then tripsq1.id end)::NUMERIC(6,4))/COUNT(tripsq1.id)::NUMERIC(6,4) AS percent_on_first_day
FROM promotionsq1
INNER JOIN couponsq1
ON promotion_id = promotionsq1.id
INNER JOIN tripsq1
ON couponsq1.id = coupon_id
INNER JOIN regionsq1
ON  regionsq1.id = region_id
WHERE promotion_name = 'TestPromo'
GROUP BY region_name;
```

and get the following result

```
 region_name    | trips | unique_users | first_day | percent_on_first_day
-------------------+-------+--------------+-----------+-----------------------
 A              |     3 |            2 |         1 |   33.3333333333333333
 B              |     1 |            1 |         0 |
 C              |     1 |            1 |         1 | 2000.0000000000000000
```

The first rows percentage gets calculated correctly while the third rows percentage is 20 times what it should be. The percent_on_first_day should be 100.00 since it is 100.0 * 1/1.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Remove `GROUP BY` + all aggregate functions to first ensure you select what you expect (apparently you're having a cartesian product somewhere)

Comment: What is the correct result? Can you add it into the question? also can you add '(SUM(case when consumed_at = start_at  then tripsq1.id end)::NUMERIC(6,4))' SUM_FIRST_DAY as new column, then post out the new output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suspecting that the issue is because of this code:

```
SUM(case when consumed_at = start_at  then tripsq1.id end)
```

This tells me you are summing the ids, which is meaningless. You probably want:

```
SUM(case when consumed_at = start_at  then 1 end)
```

Comment: Could you explain to me the "then 1 end" part, please?

Comment: It means that every time consumed_at = start_at, add 1 to the SUM